# Sorta date depending by Variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to see if row B shows "Open or awaiting"(The cell will have either -"Complete, open, Awaiting" if either Open or awaiting then I Want to then use column D to look at the date and show me the oldest open or awaiting.  Ultimately what I am trying to do is find the oldest ticket that is assigned open or awaiting.

=MIN(IF(B:B="Completed, Awaiting",D:D))

Comment: Cells either have 'Complete', 'Open' or 'Awaiting' is how I read this.... and you search for a string in these cells that's not any of those options? 'Completed, Awaiting'?

Comment: Just completed or Awaiting but three possible variables in cell

Comment: `=MIN(IF((B:B="Completed")+(B:B="Awaiting"),D:D))` with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Answer (score 0):

=MIN(IF((B:B="Completed")+(B:B="Awaiting"),D:D))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).